# Hyperledger fabric peer docker instance exiting after network setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have set up an 8-org single-channel fabric network. I am able to make the whole network setup. But after the setup is successful. Some of the docker instances stop listening to their respective ports. When I do `docker ps -a` it shows the status for some peer nodes images to be exited, that is the reason it's not able to listen at that port, thus chaincode installation fails. Is this error occurring because of docker or some error in peer configuration?

[image]

logs of one of the exited container

[image]

Comment: Can we have more log on the exited peer ? Also , are you sure they are not trying to bind themselves to already taken ports ?

Comment: No these ports are not already taken. Even the exited peer is randomly exiting. Like sometimes peer4 would work fine peer8 work exit. If run the network script again it happens that peer8 works fine but peer3 would exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log , it seems that multiple container a trying to access the same database , ("document update conflict") ; how did you configure your database ? Can we see your configurations files ? (configtx and/or docker-compose file) ?

A CouchDB container is specific for a given peer , if two  or more peer try to acces the same CouchDB , it can have unwanted consequence (like crash).

Answer (score 0):

In your configtx.yaml file you need to add atleast one Anchor Peer for all of your 8 orgs to listen to channel anchor peers like this [image]
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary.html#anchor-peer
here in anchor peer docs you can see each org must have atleast one anchor peer